# Enable xml files in outlook owa

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

We are using O365 subscription and the outlook web client (owa) for our mail.

It feels somewhat strange to me, that by default all xml files are blocked to user. Even if I'm administrator, it shows all attached xml files with forbidden sign.

When I click on that it says: "Access to this attachment is blocked. Recipients may not be able to view the attachment, either".

I have looked through all administrative and user settings and couldn't find the place where i could unblock xml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I can't find the place where I could unblock xml files.

> This tip explains how to allow or block file types in OWA for Exchange 2013 and Office 365
>
> With Exchange 2003 we had to make changes to the Registry in order to allow or block particular file types in OWA, and in Exchange 2007 we had to configure OWAs’ virtual directories. Since Exchange 2010 that this is done through Outlook Web App Mailbox Policies and this applies to the latest Exchange 2013 and Exchange Online.
>
> To check which files are currently being blocked, and to change this
>   if necessary, first connect to your exchange online service via
>   powershell.
>
> ```
> $cred = Get-Credential
> $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
> Import-PSSession $session
> ```
>
> After successfully connecting, run the following cmdlet to check what
>   file types are being blocked:
>
> ```
> Get-OwaMailboxPolicy <Policy Name> | Select -ExpandProperty BlockedFileTypes | Sort
> ```
>
> If you want to make changes and allow certain file types, such as XML
>   files for example, you remove the .xml from the BlockedFileTypes and
>   BlockedMimeTypes lists and add it to the AllowedFileTypes and
>   AllowedMimeTypes lists:
>
> ```
> Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedFileTypes @{Remove = ".xml"}
> Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -AllowedFileTypes @{Add = ".xml"}
> Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy -BlockedMimeTypes @{Remove = "text/xml", "application/xml"}
> Get-OwaMailboxPolicy | Set-OwaMailboxPolicy –AllowedMimeTypes @{Add = "text/xml", "application/xml"}
> ```
>
> Remember to ensure the settings in the ECP at permissions -> Outlook
>   Wep App policies -> file access match those in servers -> virtual
>   directories -> owa (Default Web Site) -> file access in terms of
>   Direct File Access which enables or disables direct access to all file
>   types in OWA. If this parameter is set to $False, users will not be
>   able to click on attachments in e-mails to open or save the files. The
>   attachment is visible, but the link is grayed out.

Source [Allow XML files in Office 365 OWA](http://www.msexchange.org/kbase/ExchangeServerTips/MicrosoftOffice365/ExchangeOnline/allow-xml-files-office-365-owa.html)

See also [Office 365 users can't open or view attachments in Outlook Web App](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2852113/office-365-users-can-t-open-or-view-attachments-in-outlook-web-app) (Official Microsoft page).

Comment: First-party source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2852113/office-365-users-can-t-open-or-view-attachments-in-outlook-web-app

Comment: @thims Good find. Added to answer.

Comment: This works perfectly. If there is already an active session in owa, then after changes refresh is needed - onpage navigation doesn't refresh access policies.